# Integrate web app symfony2 with asterisk server

Tags: php, sql, symfony, curl, asterisk

I'm new about Asterisk, it's already installed and I have all host details, what I need is how to use Asterisk in my symfony2 web application; Someone have an idea or he worked on this before?

My objectives: Client (SIP phone, I use 3CX phone) dial to asterisk server, asterisk then connect with external relational database (not located in the same place with asterisk server), and if database response something, asterisk server play a voice file (predefined .gsm file) to response client.

What I already have: I have installed Asterisk in VirtualBox as a asterisk server, the client is using softphone to connect with Asterisk server in SIP channel. When the Client dial to asterisk server, the server can execute the dialplan.In the other hand the administrator (through the web app) can add extensions and sip accounts.

So my question is how to save data from the web app into the asterisk database or into configuration files like sip.conf and extension.conf?

Comment: Most of this seems to be a deliberate duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524035/how-to-integrate-asterisk-server-with-external-relational-database-like-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ARA (Asterisk Realtime Architecture), in ARA you can directly save the data from webpanel into a flatfile or asteriskcdrdb database. When the table is changed (sip user added or deleted) the asterisk will immidiately reflect the changes.

[Asterisk ARA link](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Sip)

Comment: i already tried your method my friend, i created the database and the tables as it said in the link, but when i tried to make a test with softphone app like zoiper, i can't even register my account which it was insert in the first place into the table of sip users.